# What does avrdude "programmer is out of sync" mean?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avrdude

Lately, I've been getting a lot of "`programmer is out of sync`" messages while uploading to a microcontroller (ATMega328p). I am very clueless here as the uploading process just randomly succeed and sometimes just doesn't, without any changes. Here's an example of the console from the 'super verbose' mode:

```
avrdude: Send: V [56] @ [40] . [00] . [10] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [84] 
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
avrdude: Send: V [56] H [48] . [00] . [10] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [a5] 
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
avrdude: Send: V [56] @ [40] . [00] . [11] . [80]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [83] 
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
avrdude: Send: V [56] H [48] . [00] . [11] . [91]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [a7] 
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
```

What does "`programmer is out of sync`" mean? What are the possible causes?

P.S. If you need to know, I am using Eclipse CDT with Jantje's Arduino plugin, not the Arduino IDE.

Comment: have you tried to google it? This is what most of us are going to do in attempt to answer your question. I did already and there are hundreds of results.

Comment: I have tried looking up on both Google and SO on several occasions and found the answer spread across the internet. As I haven't found any 'central' place to look for, I thought that asking this question might be helpful to others. In addition, I am not aware of any answers regarding what "programmer is out of sync" actually means, including the [avrdude documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude.html).